# Error whlie using React.createRef - "You must pass either a valid element or a valid id"

Tags: reactjs, vimeo-api

I have the following code:

```
import Vimeo from '@vimeo/player';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.videoRef= React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const player = new Vimeo(this.videoRef);
  }

  render() {
   return (
    <item><iframe ref={this.videoRef} /></item>
  )
 }
}
```

However, I get for `new Vimeo(this.videoRef)` and error

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): You must pass either a valid element or a valid id.
```

What is wrong?

Comment: What is `Vimeo`?

Comment: added import. thanks!

Comment: try using `const player = new Vimeo(this.videoRef.current)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of my knowledge, this would do the job

`const player = new Vimeo(this.videoRef.current)`

Here you are creating a ref using React.createRef. It stores the refernce to the element inside the `current` field.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to do something similar to this; (https://jsfiddle.net/oLpz88mL/13/) you can view this example on fiddle for knowledge base. 
**HTML**

```
<div id="ad-slot">
  <iframe width="100%" height="480" src="//fiddle.jshell.net/zx488o9u/9/show/light/" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
// Player 1
var player1 = document.getElementById('player1');
var doc = player1.ownerDocument;
var win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow;

console.log(player1 instanceof win.HTMLElement);

// Player 2
var iframe = document.getElementById('ad-slot').childNodes[1];
var idocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
var player2 = idocument.getElementById('player2');
var doc = player2.ownerDocument;
var win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow;

console.log(player2 instanceof win.HTMLElement);
```

Comment: React is in JavaScript right? You can figure out to curl out the javascript syntax. I am sorry though if you think it doesn't

Comment: it is.. but I want to use react createRef method